# How to access volley response like this

Tags: android, android-volley

How to access volley response `{"data":"success"}` like this.

i am already try this

```
                    JSONObject j = null;
                    try {

                        j = new JSONObject(response);

                        result = j.getJSONArray("data");

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Comment: Its a `JSONObject` not a `JSONArray`.

Comment: ok, how to access it

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to access a `JSONArray` from a `JSONObject` while it's just a string. So just replace `getJSONArray` with `getString` and try this

```
String data = new JSONObject(response).getString("data");
```

Or in your code

```
try {
    JSONObject j = new JSONObject(response);
    result = j.getString("data");
} 
catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: success couldn't print

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: {"data":"success"}

Comment: i cannot toast success

Comment: Okay, thanks for the information, what can I do about it? You give minimal information.

Answer (score 0):

**Access Like This**

```
 JSONObject j = null;
                try {

                    j = new JSONObject(response);

                    result = j.getString("data");

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check this, before retrieving check if that tag (i.e. "data" for your case) is exists on that json object.

```
JSONObject j = null;
try {
     j = new JSONObject(response);
     if(j.has("data") {
         result = j.getString("data");
     }
} catch (JSONException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the value of `data` is `string` and to get `string` value you have to use `JSONObject.getString("data")`

**Use:**

```
result = j.getString("data");
```

**Instead of:**

```
result = j.getJSONArray("data");
```